# Append is just printing the text and not printing the data from my api...Please solve only using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

This is my html

```
              <tbody id="rqstusers">

              </tbody>
```

This is my script and when i run it its just pasting the lines

```
function getusersdata() {
      const myHeaders = new Headers();
      myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      const url = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
      fetch(url)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response.status);
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var mydata = "<tr><td>" + data[i].name + "</td><td>" + data[i].email + "</td><td>" + data[i].mobilenumber + "</td><td>"
              + data[i].state + "</td><td>" + data[i].city + "</td><td>" + data[i].pincode + "</td></tr>";
            rqstusers.append(mydata);
          }

        })
```

This is my output
[image]

UPDATED: Updated my code to

```
.then(function (data) {
      var elem = document.getElementById("rqstusers");
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var mydata = "<tr><td>" + data[i].name + "</td><td>" + data[i].email + "</td><td>" + data[i].mobilenumber + "</td><td>"
          + data[i].state + "</td><td>" + data[i].city + "</td><td>" + data[i].pincode + "</td></tr>";
        elem.innerHTML= elem.innerHTML + mydata;
      }
```

This is my Output and due to that first row its considering my table as empty and search ,print , csv functions were not working now
[image]

Comment: So you need to make it HTML elements, not a string.

Comment: Can't get u bruh can u xplain me a bit more...I m new to JavaScript

Comment: You'll probably need to do something like `document.getElementById('rqstusers').innerHTML=mydata;`

Comment: Kkk will try nd update u bruh....

Comment: The data got binded but now the problem is its only binding the last index data...I think instead of innerhtml we shld use append or somethng

Comment: Ah okay sorry. Try something like
`var elem=document.getElementById('rqstusers');
elem.innerHTML=elem.innerHTML+mydata;`
That should append the new data each time through the loop

Comment: Ya thanks data got binded but first row of my table is showing no data even if i have data...what may be the reason???The data is not bnding correctly... Print and CSV are also not working it showing empty

Comment: I have updated my post can u have a look at it @sbrass

Comment: Are you using a library to initialize the table? If so, you should construct the html and then initialize the table once the data is all there

Comment: Shld i store all the data from for loop in a variable and then assign the variable to table after the for loop???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177124/discussion-between-sbrass-and-gvs-akhil).